# Which of these two is the best way to write SASS

Tags: css, sass

I wanted to ask when wrting SASS does it matter which way I format the code in regards to the two examples provided below? Please see the following two options that both output the same CSS.

```
@include breakpoint(large) {
.bookhome{
padding-top: 0; }}
```

or

```
.bookhome{
@include breakpoint(large) {
padding-top: 0; }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a very subjective question. Everyone has their own opinion and preference for structuring their CSS. I therefore don't think there's a right or wrong answer.

Personally, I prefer to nest my breakpoints within my CSS selector as follows, so that you can see how the styles change between breakpoints at a glance.

```
.example {
    // mobile

    @include breakpoint(small) {
        // tablet
    }

    @include breakpoint(medium) {
        // desktop
    }

    @include breakpoint(large) {
        // large desktop
    }

    &--modifier {
        // mobile

        @include breakpoint(small) {
            // tablet
        }

        @include breakpoint(medium) {
            // desktop
        }

        @include breakpoint(large) {
            // large desktop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks I was not sure if one way was incorrect, good to know can be either based on personal experience.

Comment: At the end of the day, your styles are going through a pre-processor, which is going to change the structure anyway.

Comment: Oh with `&--modifier`, is that like if I was to add for example `h3`

Comment: `&` has the value of the previous selector. So `&--modifier` would result in a class of `.example--modifier`.

Comment: I do it like Rob. Compressing and gzipping the CSS anyway.